# Get string between two other strings

Tags: php, string, substring

For example:

```
$str = "This is my string.";
$startafter = "This is";
$endbefore = ".";
```

I need `$output = "my sting";` (I will `trim()` it to remove the space before 'my.')

How can I do this in PHP? Thank you.

Comment: Will be there special characters in your strings? Or just normal string? If just normal string without special characters, then see my answer below...

Comment: There's a . in his example

Comment: It will not fail on "." - test it in Regex tester.

Comment: @Legionar No special chars in the substring itself, but there will be special chars in both `$startafter` and `$endbefore`. (`$endbefore = ':';`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match("/".preg_quote($startafter)."(.*?)".preg_quote($endbefore)."/", $str, $output_array);
```

Comment: That works as long as there are no characters in the start and end strings that preg_match considers special.

Comment: It will also fail due to greedy matching. Use (.*?) instead of (.*)

Comment: I think you may have to fall back on strpos and some messy substring slicing

Comment: Nearly there. You missed a `$` before `endbefore`, and you should use `preg_quote()` to make the strings safe before adding them to the regex. `preg_match("/".preg_quote($startafter)."(.*?)".preg_quote($endbefore)."/", $str, $output_array);`

Answer (score 0):

you can use preg_replace() php default method like

```
<?php

$test = '';
$test = preg_replace("/^$startafter/i",'',$str');
$test = preg_replace("/$endbefore$/i",'',$str');

echo $test;
```

?>

Hope this will resolve your issue or something like this :)

Comment: neither works except for limited cases.. eg assuming the start and end markers appear only once in the source string. Maybe the OP can clarify how this will be used?  Otherwise I'm still thinking finding the strings with strpos and slicing from that point+the length of the start marker to the strpos of the end marker